# Is there an internet explorer equivalent to 'copy as curl?'

Tags: internet-explorer, curl

I am trying to use Fiddler to intercept my requests, but the site I am accessing uses certificates which has its own complications, so I was hoping for a simpler solution that was built in to IE. I know there is a 'copy as curl' feature in in chrome and firefox's developer tools. The site I am trying to access is only compatible with IE.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the image below Internet Explorer does not have any inbuilt **Copy as Curl** option and also it does not has any similar or alternative option which do the same.

[image]